# Tensorflow flow does not generate any model files

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I am trying to generate a model for my own data set following this code in 
https://github.com/llSourcell/A_Guide_to_Running_Tensorflow_Models_on_Android/blob/master/tensorflow_model/mnist_convnet.py

I am using

Language: Python 2.7
Virtual Machine OS: a virtual machine Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit, Memory: 2.0 GB
Host Machine OS: Windows 7

My data set consists of two classes and each class has 5 image samples (.png format). Data are stored in file system. To handle this, I followed earlier post "Tensorflow read images with labels".

So my program reads a text file first containing image file path and label. Each image has 3 channels.

However, whenever I run my code, it does not generate any output model and does not show any warning or error.

Here is my code https://gist.github.com/mfaisal/0cab7f8962f115444454f267edd9af7b

Any help is very appreciated.